# Sample Java code for writing JSON responses to Cassandra?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, cassandra

Simple question here I'm having issues with, only tutorials I've found have generated a lot of errors in my IDE (Eclipse with Maven).  I can read my JSON responses now, but I want to write (and eventually transform them) them to my Cassandra DB.  Anyone have some basic code they could share to get me started on this?

Answer (score 1):

The datastax java-driver includes several examples for writing / reading JSON from cassandra using Jackson, Jsr353, or plain text it can be found in driver-examples [here](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.1.0/driver-examples/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/examples/json).

Here's an example from PlainTextJson.java showing how to insert as a string:

```
private static void insertWithCoreApi(Session session) {
    // Bind in a simple statement:
    session.execute("INSERT INTO examples.querybuilder_json JSON ?",
            "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Mouse\", 
               \"specs\": { \"color\": \"silver\" } }");

    // Bind in a prepared statement:
    // (we use a local variable here for the sake of example, but in a real application you would cache and reuse
    // the prepared statement)
    PreparedStatement pst = session.prepare(
        "INSERT INTO examples.querybuilder_json JSON :payload");
    session.execute(pst.bind()
            .setString("payload", 
                "{ \"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Keyboard\",
                   \"specs\": { \"layout\": \"qwerty\" } }"));

    // fromJson lets you provide individual columns as JSON:
    session.execute("INSERT INTO examples.querybuilder_json " +
                    "(id, name, specs)  VALUES (?, ?, fromJson(?))",
            3, "Screen", "{ \"size\": \"24-inch\" }");
}
```